# Count of column values in Table 1 present in Table 2 column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables

table 1

| product_name | ID. |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |
| abc | 456 |

table 2

| product_name | ID. |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 123 |

report layout
[image]

I want to know how many of them downloaded the trial product and out of those how many purchased. Left side trials, right sight purchases

PS: columns are not unique

Comment: do you have relation between tables?

Comment: @mkRabbani - No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Count1 = calculate(DISTINCTCOUNT(table1[id])
    Count2 = Calcluate(DISTINCTCOUNT(table2[id]),
           INTERSECT(SELECTCOLUMNS(TABLE2, "id", [ID]), SELECTCOLUMNS(TABLE1, "id", [ID])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is rather vague. I am not sure what values you have in both tables.
You want for the "left visual" count unique IDs, right?

```
LeftVisual = calculate( DISTINCTCOUNT(table1[id])
```

And for the right side you want to count ID from Table2 only when that IDs appear in Table1?

```
RightVisual = calculate ( DISTINCTCOUNT(table2[id], TREATAS(table2[id],table1[id])  ))
```

Comment: I got an error: TREATAS expects a value, not a column.